# Why does printing out max int cause compile error in golang?

Tags: go

Here is a link to [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hlnsxqg9Dt)

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "math"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    fmt.Println(math.MaxUint32)
}
```

The above code seems to cause

```
constant 4294967295 overflows int
```

does `fmt.Println` convert every number to int automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants)
>
> An untyped constant has a default type which is the type to which the
>   constant is implicitly converted in contexts where a typed value is
>   required. The default type of an untyped constant is bool, rune, int,
>   float64, complex128 or string respectively, depending on whether it is
>   a boolean, rune, integer, floating-point, complex, or string constant.

```
func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)

fmt.Println(math.MaxUint32)
```

`math.MaxUint32` is an untyped integer constant that defaults to type `int` in this context, an untyped integer constant argument for a type `interface{}` parameter.

`int` is a signed 32- or 64-bit integer depending on the implementation.

```
const (
    MaxInt32  = 1<<31 - 1
    MaxUint32 = 1<<32 - 1
)
```

`MaxUint32` is greater than `MaxInt32`.

if you run `go env` you should see that you are using a 32-bit architecture, for example, `GOARCH="386"`.

Don't accept the default 32-bit `int` type. Use a compatible type conversion. For example, write

```
fmt.Println(uint32(math.MaxUint32))
```